# google speech recognition offline linux

Tags: linux, speech-recognition

When I was doing some research on speech recognition, I saw some articles about the google speech recognition service on android being able to be downloaded and used offline on android. I also saw some stuff about using the google speech service over the computer, but it involved querying the google server. So here's my question: is there any way to use the google speech recognition service offline over the computer, specifically on linux?

Comment: The issue with Palaver is that it requires connectivity to Google. There's a few variants of Sphinx (CMU Sphinx, Sphinx-4, etc.) that work offline. They are much more difficult to set up and train.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Palaver](https://github.com/JamezQ/Palaver) developed by *James McClain*.

For more details look this *video*(http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxom292XW_g).

Dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sox python-argparse libsox-fmt-mp3 mutt xvkbd xautomation
```

The current code is beta, and will be going through restructuring changes as it moves from git to launchpad, so expect a lot of changes in the near future.

The beta can actually do quite a lot at the moment, especially if you add your own dictionary.

Have a look at the docs (`/opt/Palaver/Docs`) for setting up a dictionary of commands. It is very easy to do. Also, have a look at the default dictionary for a list of inbuilt commands.

Comment: This uses the Google Speech API--it's not offline.